# Insulation in attic above garage

Tags: insulation, garage, attic

I live in south Alabama very hot and humid and mild winters with very few really cold days. I am looking at adding insulation above my garage to add a/c and was wondering if I need to have a vapor barrier and if so does it need to go toward the garage or towards the roof? Thank you

Answer (score 3):

[In humid climates or areas where there is extensive use of air-conditioning, if a vapor retarder is required, it should be installed on the exterior side of the wall.](https://insulationinstitute.org/im-a-building-or-facility-professional/residential/installation-guidance-2/moisture-management/vapor-retarders/#:%7E:text=In%20humid%20climates%20or%20areas,exterior%20side%20of%20the%20wall.)

Same would apply to your ceiling and, yes, you should use one if you are going to have a finished ceiling.